# Hash class not found Laravel 5, at model level, looking for App\Hash?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building my first Laravel application, and I'm trying to figure out how I should be hashing passwords at a model level.

The issue is, when trying to use the Laravel `Hash::` class, it can't be found. I've attempted to look up the relevant API documentation, but can't find anything apart from some references to `Illuminate` namespace classes - and from what I gather `Hash::` should be globally available?

I'm new to PHP namespacing, and I'm guessing this may have something to do the with the issue, as the error states it's looking for `App\Hash` and I know it's not part of the `App` namespace, but the `Illuminate` one.

Here's my code:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'default_currency', 'default_timezone', 'default_location', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

}
```

Any help in figuring out the route cause of this, and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to import the \Hash class, or call it with `\Hash::make()`. Just doing `Hash` as you are looks within the namespace of the class you're calling it from. The `Hash` class is part of the root namespace, or `\`.

`\Hash` is a 'Facade' class, which just basically allows you to call static globally, from anywhere, without necessarily needing to import the original class. More information can be found on the [documentation page for Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades).

Answer (score -1):

use Hash;
after namespace App include use hash line it must work.